# Where can I find VFR approach charts for Italy?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, visual-flight-rules

Has anyone a good source of **free** information for VFR approach charts in Italy? I know that for major airports (e.g. LIMW), https://www.enav.it publishes the charts.

However for small airfields (e.g. LIVV), I was not able to find anything. I am looking for something like [this](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/documents/htmlshow?f=dvd/eAIP_27_JAN_2022/Atlas-VAC/home.htm), from France.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, in Italy, VFR approach charts are published by [ENAV](https://www.enav.it/) for major airports only (you could get them georeferenced for free using [Airmate](https://www.airmate.aero) app). For small airfields and ultralight bases, the main source is  [Avioportolano](https://www.avioportolano.it/en/) but it is a commercial source. There is no free information source to the best of my knowledge.

In France, the source you quote [SIA Service de l'Information Aéronautique](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/) is indeed the right one for all airfields having an ICAO code assigned. In addition, you have more than 700 ultralight airfields having numeric codes assigned by the ULM Federation (such LF8357 for Pampelonne). You could find for them free information and charts on [FFPULM BASULM site](https://basulm.ffplum.fr/).

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend two free solutions which are using the official government (ENAV) issued charts:

[openaip.net](https://www.openaip.net/map#7.17/45.429/12.388) 
[openflightmaps.org](https://www.openflightmaps.org/li-italy/?airac=2205&language=local)

Openflightmaps is maintained by the [University of Graz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Graz):

> The mission of the project is to develop and maintain a universal
> database of aeronautical data, in order to facilitate the rendering of
> high quality VFR maps to assist the general aviation community.

You can generate pdf exports for kneeboard printouts or iPad reference easily:

[image]